# Simple: check if volume group is found with a if

Tags: 12.04, bash, command-line

I am working on a script to check if volume group vg0 exist. The problem is that it return Found even when I delete the volume group. So very unsure what is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

if vgdisplay | grep 'vg0' | awk '{print $3}'; then
  echo "Found"
else
  echo "Not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` condition in this case is evaluated based on the exit code of `awk`, which is likely to be zero unless one of the previous commands in the pipeline *failed to execute*.

You could use the `-q` option for `grep` instead:

```
if vgdisplay | grep -q 'vg0'; then
  echo "Found"
else
  echo "Not found"
fi
```

The same could also be written as:

```
vgdisplay | grep -q 'vg0' && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
```

Comment: You can also use `vgs` instead of `vgdisplay`; you can do similer things with `pvs` for physical volumes and `lvs` for logical volumes too.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is more correct:
`vgdisplay 'vg0' && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"`

The condition that you use only care the exit code of grep. Either grep can find the vg or not in the output text of vgdisplay, it will return with success code. So your statement will always return 'Found'.